# How to get a float value with a string as input parameter in Python?

Tags: python

**I wrote the following:**

```
def payment(order):

B = 2.00
W = 2.50
S = 1.50

order = ["B", "W", "S"]

return(order)

payment('BBSWS')
```

I need to get ***9.5 as output***, however, my output is ('B', 'W', 'S').

What do I need to change in my code to get the right answer 9.5?

Thank you.

Comment: Erm… everything, I guess. The code above is unrelated to the described problem. Hint: do you know what `for` loop is?

Comment: @Błotosmętek Thank you for your quick respone. However, I'm a Python beginner. I know Python For Loops but I got several times errors. Therefore I tried this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED:

```py
def payment(order):
    total = 0
    data = {"B": 2.00, "W": 2.50, "S": 1.50}
    for i in order:
        total += data.get(i, 0)
    return total

print(payment("BBSWS"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! However, I get the following error:      ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-5f157dd49e51> in <module>
      6     return sum
      7 
----> 8 print(payment("BBSWS"))

<ipython-input-29-5f157dd49e51> in payment(order)
      1 def payment(order):
----> 2     order = order.split("")
      3     data = {"B": 2.00, "w": 2.50, "S": 1.50}
      4     for i in order:
      5         sum += data[i]

ValueError: empty separator

Comment: `order = order.split("")` - this operation is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understand what you mean :

```
def payment(arg):
    letters = {'B': 2.00, 'W': 2.50, 'S': 1.50}
    order = 0
    for item, value in letters.items():
        order += arg.count(item)*value

    return(order)

print(payment('BBSWS'))
```

Comment: I like this one, but using `sum()` and a generator expression instead of for loop would be even neater.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple task with reduce and a mapping:

```
mapping = {'B': 2.00, 'W': 2.50, 'S': 1.50}
payment = lambda order: sum(map(mapping.get, order))

payment('BBSWS')
>>> 9.5
```